# Page Reload Fail in Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, custom-button, internet-explorer

I have a custom button that when checked updates a field on the product object, and displays a couple of messages to the user which need to be clicked through.

When the page reloads in Internet Explorer it takes me to the page that says "URL No Longer Exists". However this does not happen in Chrome or Firefox. instead of pulling through the record Id, it puts "e" onto the end of the URL. for example; "https://cs87.salesforce.com/undefined/e"

Any idea why the page does not reload to show the original record in Internet Explorer, but works fine in Chrome or Firefox?

```
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/29.0/connection.js")} 
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/29.0/apex.js")} 

var r = confirm("Warning: this will make the R&D Project or Service available for Salesforce Opportunities, once they are added to a price list. Do you wish to proceed?"); 
if(r==true) { 

var result = sforce.apex.execute("availableForOpportunities","convertToOpportunity", 

{product2:"{!Product2.Id}"}); 
location.reload = '/'+result[0].Id+'/e'; 

// Check result in console window 
console.log(result[0]); 

// If this result starts with a string equal to the id key for the object   type you are accessing, relocate the browser to that page 

if (result[0].lastIndexOf('001',0)=== 0) { 
location.reload = '/' + result[0] + '/e'; 
} else { 
// Otherwise, show the error message to the viewer 
alert(result[0]); 
location.reload(true) 
}
}
```

Below is the class that drives the custom button.

```
global class availableForOpportunities {
WebService static String convertToOpportunity(Id product2){
    string result; // Return a string telling us if this worked or not
    Id currentProfile = UserInfo.getProfileId(); //Get the current user profile Id
    Id CurrentUser = Userinfo.getUserId();//Get the current user Id

    Set<Id> allowedProfiles = new Set<Id>();//Create a new set to profile Ids
    for(Profile p:[SELECT Id, Name FROM Profile WHERE Name = 'System Administrator']){//Get the System Administrator profile
      allowedProfiles.add(p.Id);//Add them to the set
    }

    Set<Id> allowedUsers = new Set<Id>();//Create a new set to store User Ids
    for(User u:[SELECT Id FROM User WHERE Id =  '005w0000004j93kAAA' OR Id = '005w0000004Noi6AAC' OR Id = '0058E000002CcqcQAC' OR Id = '0058E000002CcqwQAC' ]) {//Select Joy Palmer, Andy McGregor, Jeremey Sharp, and Mark O'Leary Id's} ])
    allowedUsers.add(u.Id);//Add them to the set
    }
    Product2 prod =[SELECT make_available_for_opps_and_Proposals__c, R_D_Service_Owner__r.id , Project_Owner__r.Id FROM Product2 WHERE Id = :product2]; //Get the product ]

    if( //If...
        ((currentUser == prod.R_D_Service_Owner__r.id) || // They own it
           (currentUser == prod.Project_Owner__r.id) || // They own it  
     (allowedProfiles.contains(currentProfile)) || //They're a system admin
     (allowedUsers.contains(currentUser))) // They're a specific user
    ){
        //Do stuff!
        prod.make_available_for_opps_and_proposals__c = true;

        UPDATE prod;

        result = 'This service or project is now available for opportunities';

    }

    else{//Otherwise...
    //Do nothing
    result = 'Your must be the service/project owner to make this available for opportunities';

    }
    //Return a message
    return result;    
        }
}
```

Comment: What you are getting in `result[0]`

Comment: I'm assuming you are placing that custom button on standard Page, and try to do your things with javascript code. Well there is a known issue with IE, some of the older version of IE doen't work with realtive URL if you embedding them into iframe, Try to switch your relative URL to absolute URL and then see if it works. if not then let me know

Comment: @ReshmaI have updated my code to include the apex class that works alongside the custom button.

Comment: @user2809299  Yes the javascript is updating a field on a standard page layout. How would I switch my relative URL to absolute URL, where in my button would i make that change?

Comment: @GlennDaly, Check your reload URL, Is it forming correctly in IE, you can use IE Developer debugger for that. A realtive URL is like `/...`, instead of that provide full URL, with Salesfroce instance URL along with page url like `https<instance>.salesfroce.com/<apex:page>`

Comment: @GlennDaly you are passing a string as `result`. So how would you get value here `result[0].Id `. From your apex class you are not passing any account id along with result.